# AVAudioPlayer not playing sounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, audio, text-to-speech

I am using Google Text To Speech API to speak an NSString and I am doing the following:

```
-(void) playSound {

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.mp3"];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        NSLog(@"YES");
    }

    NSString *stringer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", URLArray[playerInt]];
    NSLog(@"%i",playerInt);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[stringer stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] ;
    [request setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    NSURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:&response
                                                     error:&error];
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:nil];
    player.delegate = self;
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];

    NSLog(@"%@", stringer);
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)audioPlayer successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    [self playSound];
}
```

Let me explain the code. I am using this as the google text to speech api: http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?&tl=en-US&ie=UTF-8&q=Hello

I need to have large paragraphs spoken so they are being broken into multiple links which are in the array `URLArray`. Then since `URLArray` is an array with a bunch of links, I am setting `int playerInt = -1` initially (because we do playerInt+=1 afterwards setting it to 0). So as soon as the first sound is finished playing, it restarts it and sets `playerInt` one integer greater (so 1) and speaks `URLArray[playerInt]` so the second link.

There are a couple problems with this. First of all, when I run this, the audio is not even playing. Secondly, the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying method is not being called.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to set things up correctly here, so for the first part I would check to see if this:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]
```

returns `YES`. It might not have finished saving the file before you start playing it. Or for the worst case, it would take a little longer for `sendSynchronousRequest` to fail.

For the second part:

`audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` is not being called because you need to set this up:

```
player.delegate = self;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So the sound still doesnt play, but I got the `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` to work (i know because of `nslogs`). I updated my playSound method. `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]` this code returns yes. How can I if the `sendSynchronousRequest` is failing?

Comment: @ShalinShah how would you know it did finish playing if it still doesn't play?

Comment: No sound is coming out on any of the devices I tested on (and the volume was up) but I put NSLog's in the didFinishPlaying method which proved that the method was being called. Do you know why it's not playing?

Answer (score 0):

Going from what you've provided, it looks like you haven't activated the audio session. Try adding

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Comment: I tried doing this, it still doesn't play the sound. Check my update.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ARC, you will need to retain the audio so it doesn't automatically set to nil, add the following property into the header.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

I answered this to a similar issue before and it worked for them [AVAudioPlayer not playing sound IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15368399/2507277)

Hope this helps for you. 
Cheers Jim

Comment: I already had this in my .h file, sorry for not including it.